# Trying to show topological uniqueness of $\beta X$ in Conway's proof for the Stone-Cech Compactification

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-topology, compactification

As the title says, I'm trying to fill in the blank spots Conway leaves to show that if X is Tychonoff and $\Omega$ is a compact space satisfying:

a) $\pi:X\rightarrow\Omega$ is a homeomorphism onto its image
b) $\pi(X)$ is dense in $\Omega$
c) For every$f\in C_b(X)$, there exists $f'\in C(\Omega)$ such that $f=f'\circ\pi$

Then there exists a homeomorphism $g:\beta X\rightarrow \Omega$.

For background, Conway constructs $\beta X$ by considering it as a subset of $C_b(X)^*$, namely, the closure of the image of the map $\Delta:X\rightarrow (C_b(X)^*,wk^*):x\mapsto \delta_x$

My problem is the following:

Let $\{x_i\}$ be a net in X such that $\Delta(x_i)\rightarrow\tau_0\in \beta X$. Then $\{\pi(x_i)\}$ is a net in $\Omega$ and since $\Omega$ is compact, there exists a $\omega_0 \in \Omega$ such that it is a cluster point of $\pi(x_i)$. Using the properties of $\beta X$, It is pretty easy to show that $\omega_0$ is in fact the unique cluster point of $\{\pi(x_i)\}$ and so $\{\pi(x_i)\}\rightarrow \omega_0$. I want to show that if $\{y_i\}$ is another net in $X$ such that $\Delta(y_i)\rightarrow \tau_0$, then we must have that $\{\pi(y_i)\}\rightarrow \omega_0$. I'm able to show that if $\{\pi(y_i)\}\rightarrow \omega_0'$, then no element of $C(\Omega)$ can distinguish between $\omega$ and $\omega’$. I don't know where to go from here, or if this is even the right direction to be going in.

Comment: Apply Urysohn to get that $C(\Omega)$ separates the points of $\Omega$. Your train of thought then yields a well defined map $\beta X\to \Omega$ that extends $\pi$. You may continue working with this map if you wish - show that it is continuous and bijective and it must automatically be a homeomorphism by some lemma from elementary topology.

Comment: I am not extremely familiar with the wider context of Urysohn's Lemma. Would you be able to hint at how to use Urysohn to show $C(\Omega)$ separates the points of $\Omega$?

Comment: Actually I guess its not needed, you may refer to the definition of completely regular aka Tychonoff instead. A point $x$ is a closed subset in such a space so for any other point $y$ you have a continuous function separating them (compare with the definition given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space#Definitions ). In a less strict situation Urysohn and Tietze (I always mix them up) are the canonical thing to cite when you want to say continuous functions separate points.

Comment: Thank you, but how does one see that $\Omega$ is Tychonoff? Or is there some other property of $\Omega$ that is being used here?

Comment: OK, I had thought that $\Omega$ being Tychonoff was the pre-requisite. If its compact and Hausdorff its normal and you can apply Tietze / Urysohn: $\{x,y\}$ is closed and $f(x)=0$, $f(y)=1$ is continous on that set, extend continuously via Tietze to all of $\Omega$. I'm sure $\Omega$ being Hausdorff is a necessary assumption - I think the theorem (about the uniqueness of the Stone-Cech compactification) will admit exceptions if you don't assume it.

Comment: Conway doesn't seem to add $\Omega$ being Hausdorff to the hypothesis, so I thought maybe that somehow followed from its other properties, but maybe not and it is a required assumption as you've said. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does Conway follow the Bourbaki naming scheme, where compact means what everybody else understands to be compact and Hausdorff? (The usual compact is then called quasi-compact)

Comment: I'm almost certain that he uses compact to only mean that the open cover criterion is satisfied

Comment: What text of Conway is this based off?

Comment: Functional analysis (in the graduate text series)